# Nodemailer - sending from different gmail accounts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, gmail, nodemailer

On our NodeJS server, we would like to use nodemailer to send emails from multiple user accounts (those are custom accounts, so no google authentication using gmail account). We also have React application which is communicating to NodeJS server using API.

Now since some functionality is based on sending emails, we would like to use user's gmail to send out emails.

What would be the right approach, best practice here using Nodemailer?
Would authenticating user with Google API and then saving his token to send email in the future work? Would token need to be refreshed every once in a while?

What about "Less secure apps", would user still need to enable this option inside his gmail settings?

What about creating app inside Google Developer console and using it's ID and secret? Would user still need to authenticate with google?

We are just looking for the best option here so it's as clean UX as possible.
User shouldn't do anything in order for emailing to work, well except logging in which is necessary.